# R grepl inside loop

Tags: r, loops, grepl

Hello I want to add a certain value to rows which contain specific strings.
For example this works:

```
df[grepl("acting", df$Q), "QG"] <- "SP"
df[grepl("did not", df$Q), "QG"] <- "SP"
df[grepl("Somehow", df$Q), "QG"] <- "SP"
```

However I wanted to put everything in a loop to reduce code.
This doesn't work (and don't understand why)

```
assignSubgroup <- function(keywords, group){
  for(k in keywords){
    df[grepl(k, df$Q), "QG"] <- group
  }
}

assignSubgroup(c("acting", "did not", "Somehow"), "SP")
```

It doesn't throw errors but it does nothing to the dataframe. What's the issue?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have to create a function and use a loop?

Comment: `df[grepl("acting|did not|Somehow", df$Q), "QG]  = "SP"`

Comment: Use: `paste0(c("acting", "did not", "Somehow"), collapse = "|")` to create the pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R and no function or loop:

```
df$QC[grepl("acting|did not|Somehow", df$Q)] <- "SP"
```